# How to set a predefined string as "wb"

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to set a workbook as a dimension. This workbook is already defined as a string. However, when I go to set this string as "wb", I get a type mismatch error...

Current lines are:

```
Dim History as String

History = "Filename.xlsx" 

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = History
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way:

```
Dim History as String
History = "Filename.xlsx"

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks(History)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks chaps. I did already have a workbook open line however this was placed after setting dimensions etc... Still learning! One more question, my question got downvoted, any ideas why? Just so I know how to post less downvote-able questions in future... I did try to edit to properly format the code etc... Maybe it was just a silly question to begin with!

Comment: Don't worry about the downvote - it's not a "bad" question

Answer (score 0):

Tim's solution assumes that `FileName.xlsx` is already open.  If it is not then:

```
Sub TomHolland()
    Dim History As String
    History = "Filename.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open "C:\TestFolder\" & History
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub
```

or something similar